# How to keep the data in localStorage after refreshing?

Tags: reactjs

I am using react to write a Child component. This child component gets its states from its Parent component.

```
Class ChildDetails extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          messageId: this.props.messageId,
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        localStorage.setItem("messageId", this.props.messageId);
    }
}
```

I am sure that when the Child component is rendered at first, the data is stored into the localStorage. But when I want to get the data from localStorage after refreshing the page, the localStorage is cleared. I think it may be because I am using a local development environment, I use

```
localhost:3000
```

to access my application. But I don't know why.

My Parent component is the root App, I use `Route` to pass the data to the Child component. The data is from the `redux` store.

```
<Route
    path="/messageDetails"
    render={(props) => (
    <Child
     {...props}
     messageId={this.props.messageId}
     />
  )}
></Route>

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    messageId: state.Reducer.messageId,
}
```

Comment: What is the value of ```this.props.messageId``` in ```componentDidMount````?

Comment: When this component mounts, do you have an item in local storage?

Comment: `this.props.messageId` in `componentDidMount` is the `messageId` from the Parent component, they are all the same.

Comment: @Hyetigran After the component is mounted, I check the localStorage in the Browser, and it has the values from the Parent component. But when I refresh the page, the localStorage is cleared, the keys are still there, but the values are cleared.

Comment: I think the issue is due to the way you're saving state and mounting component. Could you please share your Parent component as well.

Comment: @Hyetigran The data is from a `redux` store. I update it in the question body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you refresh your browser, your components will re-render and call the componentDidMount lifecycle method. So I think the error might come from the fact that your `messageId` might be undefined. One way to avoid this is to add a conditional so that if you have a an item in localStorage, it won't try to set it.

```
Class ChildDetails extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          messageId: this.props.messageId,
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        if(!localStorage.getItem("messageId")){
            localStorage.setItem("messageId", this.props.messageId);
        }
    }
}
```

As an aside, I would advise against saving messageId into ChildDetails state as the intention of redux is to place state in a central location and feed it into components as necessary.

Comment: It works. Also, in case the localStorage is cleared and the component is re-entered, `{localStorage.getItem("messageId")
            ? localStorage.getItem("messageId")
            : this.props.messageId}` should be used